# Calling Seq.skip and Seq.take in F#

Tags: f#, sequences

```
let aBunch = 1000
let offset = 0

let getIt offset =
  MyIEnumerable
  |> Seq.skip aBunch * offset
  |> Seq.take aBunch
  |> Seq.iter ( .. some processing ...)
```

Calling getIt() with different offsets eventually gives me an 'Invalid operation' exception with additional info that 'the input sequence had insufficient elements'

I try to understand why, as both the Seq.Skip and Seq.take do not generate an exception according to the online documentation [FSharp Collections](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/FSharp.Core/Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Seq.html)

Version: (Visual Studio 2010) Beta 1

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything about exceptions; the docs are incomplete.  I'll file a doc bug.

Answer (score 29):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone comes across this in a search the way I did:

You can use [Seq.truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370325(VS.100).aspx) if you want at most *n* items. It won't throw an exception if fewer than *n* items are available.

Comment: this only applies to the `Seq.take` part of the question, not `Seq.skip`, I guess?

Answer (score 7):

Both Seq.skip and Seq.take will throw this exception if called with a value larger than the sequence. You can check the source code in Seq.fs to see why:

```
let skip count (sequence: seq<_>) =
    { use e = sequence.GetEnumerator() 
      let latest = ref (Unchecked.defaultof<_>)
      let ok = ref false
      for i in 1 .. count do
          if not (e.MoveNext()) then 
              raise <| System.InvalidOperationException "the input sequence had insufficient elements" 
      while e.MoveNext() do
          yield e.Current }

let take count (sequence : seq<'T>)    = 
    if count < 0 then invalidArg "count" "the number of elements to take may not be negative"
    (* Note: don't create or dispose any IEnumerable if n = 0 *)
    if count = 0 then empty else  
    { use e = sequence.GetEnumerator() 
      for i in 0 .. count - 1 do
          if not (e.MoveNext()) then
              raise <| System.InvalidOperationException "the input sequence had insufficient elements" 
          yield e.Current }
```

Answer (score 3):

For an exceptionless `skip` you can add your own version to the Seq module like this:

```
module Seq =
    let skipSafe (num: int) (source: seq<'a>) : seq<'a> =
        seq {
            use e = source.GetEnumerator()
            let idx = ref 0
            let loop = ref true
            while !idx < num && !loop do
                if not(e.MoveNext()) then
                    loop := false
                idx := !idx + 1

            while e.MoveNext() do
                yield e.Current 
        }
```

Combined with `Seq.truncate` (which is an exceptionless `Seq.take` equivalent - it will take as much items are available without throwing an exception).

```
[1..10] 
|> Seq.skipSafe 20
|> Seq.truncate 5

(* returns empty seq *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly shorter "skipSafe" implementation using built in functions:

```
module Seq =
    let skipSafe num = 
        Seq.zip (Seq.initInfinite id)
        >> Seq.skipWhile (fun (i, _) -> i < num)
        >> Seq.map snd
```

Or if you wish to just inline it into your current pipeline directly, replace

```
|> Seq.skip num
```

with

```
|> Seq.zip (Seq.initInfinite id)
|> Seq.skipWhile (fun (i, _) -> i < num)
|> Seq.map snd
```

Answer (score 2):

```
module Seq = 
    let trySkip count source  =
        source |> Seq.indexed |> Seq.filter(fst >> (<=) count) |> Seq.map snd
```

Comment: Liked it, short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

For `skip`, you can easily define a trivial `skipSafe` with (presumably) optimal performance by delegating to LINQ's `Skip`:

```ml
open System.Linq

let skipSafe count (source: seq<'a>) = source.Skip(count)
```

For `take`, as the other answers say, you can just use `Seq.truncate`, or optionally alias it:

```ml
let takeSafe count source = Seq.truncate count source
```